# How to Calculate number of hours left for the current date in Swift

Tags: swift, calendar, countdowntimer, nsdatecomponents

I would like to count how many hours left till midnight. I have found tons of tutorials about making countdown timers, but I can't find any for calculating the left time.

Any ideas how should I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution:

```swift
let now = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: Date())
let hoursTillMidnight = 24 - now.hour!    

print(hoursTillMidnight)
```

This doesn't take into accounts things like minutes and seconds. Both 1:01 PM and 1:59 PM are 11 hours till midnight. You can round the hour up and down if you want.

---

If you are targeting newer platforms (iOS 13.5+, OS X 10.15+), and want something like "midnight in 10 hours and 25 minutes", you can use [`RelativeDateTimeFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/relativedatetimeformatter):

```swift
let now = Date()
let midnight = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: now, matching: DateComponents(hour:0), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!

let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
formatter.localizedString(for: midnight, relativeTo: now)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import Foundation

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let noonToday = calendar.dateBySettingHour(12, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: [])!
let noonishTomorow = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: noonToday, options: [])!
let midnight = calendar.startOfDayForDate(noonishTomorow)

let components = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: NSDate(), toDate: midnight, options: [])
let hoursUntilMidnight = components.hour
let minutesUntilMidnight = components.minute
```

You have to be really careful with "midnight" because it doesn't always exist, sometimes it exists twice, etc...  That's why Apple always recommends working with noon instead, as I do above.

Avoid ANY answer that tells you to explicitly set the hour to midnight and then subtract.  You just said hour, but I gave you minutes to in case you needed to see how to do that.

Comment: The 'Foundation' import is if you're on OS X.  If you're using iOS, just leave that line off as you've already included UIKit.

Answer (score 2):

## Calculating Remaining Number of Hours for the current Date:

### In Swift 5.2:

```
        let now = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: .current, from: Date())
        if let currentHour = now.hour {
          let hoursTillMidnight = 24 - currentHour
            print(hoursTillMidnight)
        }
```

Hope this will be helpful to someone out there!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Gargoyle's code no longer builds. Here is Swift 5 production code (without the force unwrapping) that I've tested.

```
extension Date {
    var minutesToMidnight: Int {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        guard let noonishTomorow = calendar.date(bySetting: Calendar.Component.hour, value: 12, of: Date()) else {
            return 0
        }
        let midnight = calendar.startOfDay(for: noonishTomorow)
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: Date(), to: midnight)
        var hoursUntilMidnight = components.hour ?? 0
        var minutesLeftInHour = components.minute ?? 0
            if minutesLeftInHour < 0 {
            minutesLeftInHour += 60
            hoursUntilMidnight -= 1
        }
        if hoursUntilMidnight < 0 {
            hoursUntilMidnight += 24
        }
        print("\(hoursUntilMidnight) hours and \(minutesLeftInHour) minutes till midnight")
        return hoursUntilMidnight * 60 + minutesLeftInHour
    }
}
```